# Edge colouring of regular vertex-transitive graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Suppose that $\Gamma = (V\Gamma, E\Gamma)$ is a locally finite simplicial graph, i.e. $V\Gamma$ is a set and the set of edges $E\Gamma \subseteq \binom{V\Gamma}{2}$ consists of unordered tuples of vertices and that for every vertex $v \in V\Gamma$ the neighbourhood $N(v) = \{u \in V\Gamma\ \mid \{u,v\} \in E\Gamma \}$ is finite. Also, assume that $\Gamma$ is vertex transitive, meaning that for every pair of vertices $u,v \in V\Gamma$ there is a graph automorphism $\alpha \in \mathop{Aut}(\Gamma)$ such that $\alpha(v) = u$. This implies that all vertices are of the same degree $d \in \mathbb{N}$.

My question is following: is there a colouring of the edges of $\Gamma$ with $d+1$ colours? In the case when $V\Gamma$ is finite the answer is positive by Vizing's Theorem, but I am not sure whether the statement still holds if the the graph is infinititely countably many vertices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes; since every finite subgraph of $\Gamma$ is $(d+1)$-edge-colorable, so is all of $\Gamma$ by the [de Bruijn–Erdős theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Bruijn%E2%80%93Erd%C5%91s_theorem_(graph_theory)) (applied to the line graph of $\Gamma$).

Comment: (If you like, I can elaborate on the compactness argument in de Bruijn–Erdős, but I wasn't sure it's necessary.)

Comment: Thanks, Misha. I was not aware of de Bruijn-Edrös theorem. My field is group theory and my knowledge of graph theory is rather superficial.

Comment: @MichalFerov If you're familiar with Tychonoff's product theorem from general topology, the de Bruijn–Erdős theorem is easily explained. If $n$ is finite, the set of all $n$-colourings (vertex, edge, whatever), **not necessarily proper** (we don't care if adjacent parts have the same colour), can be viewed as a product of $n$-element discrete spaces, therefore a compact space. The set of **proper** colourings can then be seen as the intersection of a family of closed sets with the finite intersection property.

Comment: @bof That is my preferred explanation; there's also an alternate argument using [Kőnig's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K%C5%91nig%27s_lemma), but given that it involves constructing an auxiliary infinite graph to deal with colorings of infinitely many subgraphs of the existing infinite graph, it might not be the best argument for a non-graph theorist.

Comment: As I understand it, the proof using Kőnig's lemma only works for countable graphs, which is good enough for the OP's question, but something else is needed if you need the de Bruijn-Erdös theorem for arbitrary graphs.

Comment: @bof Now we're leaving *my* domain of expertise :)

Comment: @MishaLavrov I am familiar with the Tychonoff's Theorem, it just didn't occur to me to topologise the space of colourings - it's all clear now. Thanks a lot!